# Euro rental income earned in Spain but can it be paid in Sterling in UK

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, rental-property, spain

I am a UK national with a property in Spain. The tenants of this property currently pay the monthly rental in Euros to my Spanish bank account but have asked if they can change this arrangement and pay in Sterling to my UK bank account. I will continue to declare the income to the Spanish tax authorities as a non resident but will the change of payment country cause problems?

Comment: What is the contractual amount of the rent? If it’s denominated in euro, what exchange rate do you expect them to use for the sterling conversion, do the tenants agree, and are they aware that they will have to calculate a different amount for each monthly payment as the exchange rates fluctuate?

Comment: Because I think _el negocio_ would still be taking place in Spain, I think there wouldn't be any particular important tax implications on the change. But I would ask a lawyer or a tax advisory.